# Excel: show list of values based on query in range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, query

I have a table like this:

```
a    |    tomato
b    |    pear
c    |    tomato
d    |    pear
```

I would like to create a formula that lets me select which rows contain tomato and which ones contain pear. so the outcome of the formula would be "a, c" for the query for tomato and "b, d" for the query for tomato pear.

can this be done in Excel (and if yes, how so?)

Thank you!

Comment: There is no worksheet function which (conditionally) concat the range cell's string values into one value. You can solve the task using additional columns or by user-defined function (VBA code - the simplest solution I think).

Comment: Hi Akina, thank you for your response. Can you explain what you mean by "using additional columns?" Because if I could just get a return such as a | c in two different colums, then i cold afterward concatenate those cells to get the required result.

Comment: @Akina You don't need a function that conditionally concatenates. You can generate the appropriate values with an array function, and then use either `CONCAT()` or `TEXTJOIN()`. No extra columns or VBA is required. (Unless you don't have Excel 2016, of course.)

Comment: *Unless you don't have Excel 2016, of course.* Alas, only 2010 :( ...

Comment: @Akina Just use my supplied poly-fill UDF ;-) (Or you can search for other versions online.) Btw, I'm only 2007 :-P

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished without any VBA by using the `TEXTJOIN()` function introduced in Excel 2016. If you don't have that version of Excel, you can install a poly-fill UDF. I have supplied a basic one at the end of this answer.

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Array-enter the following formula in `E2`:

```dart
{=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IFERROR(INDEX(A1:A5,N(IF(1,SMALL(IFERROR(1/(1/((B1:B5=D2)*ROW(B1:B5))),FALSE),ROW(INDEX(E:E,1):INDEX(E:E,ROWS(B1:B5))))))),""))}
```

---

The prettified formula is as follows:

```dart
{=
TEXTJOIN(
  ", ",
  TRUE,
  IFERROR(
    INDEX(
      A1:A5,
      N(IF(1,
        SMALL(
          IFERROR(1/(1/((B1:B5=D2)*ROW(B1:B5))),FALSE),
          ROW(INDEX(E:E,1):INDEX(E:E,ROWS(B1:B5)))
        )
      ))
    ),
    ""
  )
)}
```

**Notes:**

- The prettified formula actually works if entered.

---

My version of the `TEXTJOIN()` poly-fill UDF:

```vb
'============================================================================================
' Module     : <any standard module>
' Version    : 0.1.1
' Part       : 1 of 1
' References : Optional - Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5   [VBScript_RegExp_55]
' Source     : https://superuser.com/a/1331555/763880
'============================================================================================
Public Function TEXTJOIN( _
                                     ByRef delimiter As String, _
                                     ByRef ignore_empty As Boolean, _
                                     ByRef text1 As Variant _
                        ) _
       As String
       Dim ƒ As Excel.WorksheetFunction: Set ƒ = Excel.WorksheetFunction

  Const DELIMITER_ As String = "#"
  Const PATTERN_ As String = "^(?:#)+|(?:#)+$|(#){2,}"

  Static rexDelimiterEscaper As Object ' VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp ' ## Object
  Static rexEmptyIgnorer As Object ' VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp ' ## Object
  If rexEmptyIgnorer Is Nothing _
  Then
    Set rexEmptyIgnorer = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") ' New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp ' ## CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With rexEmptyIgnorer
      .Global = True
      .Pattern = PATTERN_ ' Replacement = "$1"
    End With
    Set rexDelimiterEscaper = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") ' New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp ' ## CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With rexDelimiterEscaper
      .Global = True
      .Pattern = "(.)" ' Replacement = "\$1"
    End With
  End If

  Dim varText1 As Variant
  Select Case TypeName(text1)
    Case "Range":
      varText1 = ƒ.Transpose(text1.Value2)
      If text1.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        varText1 = ƒ.Transpose(varText1)
        If text1.Columns.Count = 1 Then varText1 = Array(varText1)
      End If
    Case "Variant()":
      On Error Resume Next
        If LBound(text1, 2) <> LBound(text1, 2) Then
          varText1 = text1
        Else
          varText1 = ƒ.Transpose(text1)
        End If
      On Error GoTo 0
    Case Else:
      varText1 = Array(text1)
  End Select
  If ignore_empty _
  Then
    With rexEmptyIgnorer
      .Pattern = Replace(PATTERN_, DELIMITER_, rexDelimiterEscaper.Replace(delimiter, "\$1"))
      TEXTJOIN = .Replace(Join(varText1, delimiter), "$1")
    End With
  Else
    TEXTJOIN = Join(varText1, delimiter)
  End If

End Function
```

Notes:

- This is **not** a proper poly-fill:

  - The first two arguments are not optional;
  - If you no not wish to use a delimiter, you *must* pass an empty string as the first parameter.
  - There is only one other (also required) argument allowed.
- You can pass in anything for the third argument, **except** a multi-dimension array/range. Doing so will result in a `#VALUE!` error.
- It should be very fast, especially for large inputs, as it doesn't use any loops. If you aren't ignoring empty values, it will be lightning fast. Ignoring them will be slower as a couple of regexes and an extra string manipulation have to be used as well.

Answer (score 0):

User-defined function can help.

Imagine you have the next data on the worksheet:

```
  |  A  |  B
--+-----+---------
1 |  a  |  tomato
2 |  b  |  pear
3 |  c  |  tomato
4 |  d  |  pear
```

Open VBA editor (Alt-F11). Insert new module (Insert - Module). Insert the code below into it:

```
Public Function GetValues(rngSource As Range, strValue As String) As String
Dim i As Integer
If rngSource.Columns.Count <> 2 Then
    GetValues = "#ERROR - Source range must have 2 columns!"
    Exit Function
End If
For i = 1 To rngSource.Rows.Count
    If rngSource.Cells(i, 2) = strValue Then
        GetValues = GetValues & "," & rngSource.Cells(i, 1)
    End If
Next
GetValues = Mid(GetValues, 2)
End Function
```

Close VBA editor.

Jump to the worksheet. Insert a value "tomato" into D1 cell.

Select E1 cell. Insert the below formula into it:

```
=GetValues(A1:B4;D1)
```

The E1 cell value is 'a,c'. Change the D1 value to 'pear' - the E1 value will change. Change the D1 value to 'apple' - the E1 value will change to empty string.